http fetch reset not recognized in javascript
The following JavaScript code sends a file to an embedded LWIP HTTP server in chunks.
As can be seen in the Wireshark trace, a reset sometimes occurs during transmission. In this case, the request is aborted, however the script does not receive any information from this and returns true even in case of an error.
Does anyone have a tip on how to teach the script to recognize such an error?
The function should only return true if the request was successful, otherwise the call will repeated again with the same chunk.

async function uploadChunk(chunk) {
  let result = false;
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", chunk);
  sleep(10);
  
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://" + target_ip + "/update", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "no-cors",
      body: formData
    });
    res = await response;
    const ok_string = "OK";
    result = (response.ok & (response.statusText === ok_string));
    console.log(res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to upload chunk: ", error);
  }
  
  return result;
}


A fetch only throws an error if a network-level failure happens. You need to implement response handling yourself. Start by checking the response code - similar to how you already do with response.ok and response.statusText

res = await response; looks odd

he function should only return true the function won't ever return true ... it could return false, but it could also return 0 or 1 ... but never true - because true & false is 0 and true & true is 1 - did you mean response.ok && .....etc? - are you checking if the returned value is false and assuming if it's not then there was no issue?

The first version uses only result = response.ok; The (wrong) logic AND was only inserted out of pure depreciation. According to which criterion can i distinguish whether the fetch was successful? I thought it is response.ok != 0

Javascript can’t read the response if you specify mode:no-cors in the request.

I have removed the no-cors entry. The error pattern has not changed. The debugger in the browser shows net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK) in the event of an error. If this info would be in the response, i could react to it.

I have now implemented a ugly workaround that recognizes the packet loss on the server side and responds to the next packet with 500 ERROR This can then be recognized in the browser and responded to. If anyone else has an idea how to solve this more elegantly, I would be grateful for any tips.
